# Как выровнять элемент по горизонту, находящийся поверх другого элемента?

Tags: css, bootstrap

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.pbta_text {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.pbta p:last-child {
    font-size: 13px;
}

.pbta p:only-child {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.recent {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.info {
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(248,229,20,.9);
}

.info ul {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.info li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.recent:hover .info {
    display: block !important;

}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">


<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="recent">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://sunnyrio.beget.tech/img/man_1.jpg" alt="J D">
               
                <div class="info d-none">
                    <p>sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem.</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href=#>
                                <img src="http://sunnyrio.beget.tech/img/gplus.png">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href=#>
                                <img src="http://sunnyrio.beget.tech/img/gplus.png">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href=#>
                                <img src="http://sunnyrio.beget.tech/img/gplus.png">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
                <H5>Jonh Doeeh</H5>
                <p>Lead Designer</p>
            </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `.info ul` добавить  `padding: 0; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);`. В `.info li` убрать margin. Если он нужен, то не добавлять последнему элементу.

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;       
}
.recent {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.info {
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(248,229,20,.9);
}

.info ul {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);   
    
}
.info li {
    display: inline-block;
}
  
.info a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="recent">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://sunnyrio.beget.tech/img/man_1.jpg" alt="J D">
               
                <div class="info d-none">
                    <p>sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem.</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href=#>
                                <img src="http://sunnyrio.beget.tech/img/gplus.png">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href=#>
                                <img src="http://sunnyrio.beget.tech/img/gplus.png">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href=#>
                                <img src="http://sunnyrio.beget.tech/img/gplus.png">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>                  
            </div>
```

Comment: Почему у меня последний элемент при твоем варианте переноситься на новую строку, вниз вообщем???

Comment: можешь посмотреть на сайте http://sunnyrio.beget.tech

Comment: Можешь здесь https://habrahabr.ru/post/137582/ почить. Объясняется почему и как можно решить.